# What type/size screws to mount ceiling fan on a wooden joist

Tags: electrical, ceiling-fan

I am installing a ceiling fans in all my bedroom and one of the electrical boxes looks like this:
[image: Electrical box on ceiling]

As far as I can tell, this is mounted on the joist or wood based on the lag screw on the center.

Problem is the LED flush mount lights already there were installed with these screws:

[image: Screws]

Can I use any wood screws as long as the screw is able to sit 1.5 inches in the wood (current one are only 1.5 inches as far as I can tell and atleast 3/4th unch will not be in wood with the fan bracket in place.)?

Or do I need to go get lag bolts like the one [here](https://www.homedepot.com/p/Commercial-Electric-12-cu-in-Plastic-NM-Fan-Box-with-Plastic-Cover-CPB13NM-SM/205383211)

Comment: You need special screws rated for a fan and not just any old screws. Most fans have such screws in their hardware packet. What is the mfrgr and model of fan you want to install? is the fan a new one with all the parts or are you rehanging the old fan?  I would feel safer with screws the length and diameter of those with the new fan box.

Comment: If the pic is of the current screws, yikes and double yikes! That is a drywall screw! The screws with the new Hunter fans are 3" long, have washers, and rated to hold a fan. They have 2" of threads.

Comment: Do you have access to the ceiling above (attic?)?

Comment: @JimStewart that screw was only holding the LED box.

Comment: @Huesmann kinda but it’s covered with a board so I can walk .

Comment: I confirmed with the builder that all boxes that are in the room are fan rated. I mean they provided two swiches and one of them does nothing

Comment: The type of box shown (plastic fan box) has oblong holes in the box for LONG, SPECIAL screws that hold the fan bracket to go through the box and into the wood joist. The fan is not hanging from the box. There is another type of box which is metal and strongly secured to the joist AND has special fittings so the fan bracket can be hung from the box.

Comment: What is the brand of fan you want to install? The "extra switch that does nothing"  does plenty if it is wired correctly. It allows you to separately control a light kit which can be installed on the bottom of the fan. Do you want to do this or do you want a light on the fan or only a fan?

Comment: The cable you have from the switch box to the ceiling box has two hots (black and red) and a neutral (white) which will serve as a neutral for both hots. One hot will go to the hot of the fan (usually a black wire) and the other hot will go to the hot for the light (usually a blue wire). Your original fixture was only a light so one switch and one hot were not needed. But if you wnt to have both a light and a fan you will use both wires and both switches. I have installed about 10 fans. The wireless remote for some fans assumes you only have one hot and one switch. Do you want advice?

Comment: Given your installation you do not have to go into the attic to hang a fan. The proper screws are likely in the parts packet of your new fan.. But it is possible that the original installers left the long wood screws in their stowed position on the understide of the plastic fan box. The OP could remove the central screw holding the box to the joist, pull the box down, and take a look.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The new electrical box box comes with 10-24 lag screws.

I would use 2 1/4" or 2 1/2" long with a flat washer to hang a fan.

Comment: The screws that come with the new Hunter fans are 3" long and have 2" of wood threads. It is possible that the original installers left the long wood screws in their stowed on the understide of the plastic fan box. The OP should remove the central screw holding the box to the joist and take a look.